# How to hide ImageView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show an image to an imageView but I don't know how to hide the Image once the user clicks on a specific button, This is my code that I'm using

```
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

and the content view XML is listed below aswell

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/hide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hide Image" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "close the image"?

Comment: I'm still not sure if I'm following you, but maybe you want `iv.setImageBitmap(null);`?

Comment: By Opening image, You mean as `Dialog` or just add a `ImageView` to `Activity`?

Comment: There is no `Dialog` in your code. Please [edit] your question to explain, in detail, exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a brief search of google, all I needed to do was set an OnClickListener to the button and call `setVisibility` on the ImageView instance

```
iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```